# set up a proxy in nginx

Tags: webserver, nginx

I'm using amazon cloud. I have configured LB with SSL certificates and LB's port 443 is pointing to 80 to the instance. Nginx is running on instance on port 80. I have configured `nginx` like if some request, say abc.com, comes on port 80 of instance it will proxypass the request to another instance say xyz.com on HTTP.

But my concerns is, when I hit `https://abc.com`, it's proxypassing to`http://xyz.com`. I want that, `http://xyz.com` should show `https://xyz.com`.

How to set up a proxy in `nginx` where the client connects over HTTPS, but the proxy connects to the final destination server using HTTP?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy pass HTTPS to HTTP, but still make it show to the client's browser as HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do `http` to the backend, even when the client connects with `https` to the front-end, then in your [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass), just avoid using `$scheme://`, and use `http://` instead.  This should solve your issue.